# Move a table from one database to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `tbl_Question` in `MyDatabase` on `MySqlServer`. I want to move that table to `MyDB_2` on `MyLocalSqlServer`.

How can I do that?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1617.0

Comment: do you want to copy the table with contents or just the schema?

Comment: In SSMS, you could Right-click `MyDatabase`->Tasks->Export Data.  This allows you to export table(s).  The usage is pretty straight-forward, but you would probably want to explore in a test environment initially.

Comment: @Robert I want to copy the table with contents

Comment: How big is the table? There's the option of backing up the entire database, and then restoring it to your local server, or setting up a linked server and using OPENQUERY to get your data.

Comment: @Mihai the table is not that big has less than 100 rows (but I have to do this on couple of tables) and I tried Linked Server but I don't have admin privilege.

Comment: @AdamWenger your suggestion did the trick. If you submit your solution I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do it.  Something to consider is the permissions, I'm assuming you have rights to do any of the below items.

Export the table from the first database to the other:
[Export Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

You can do a SQL insert from one table to another:
[SQL Insert](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/)